# Local storage not storing the last added or deleted item to/from state in React app

Tags: reactjs

Im new to React and making a todo app. I am trying to store my todos in local storage. But when i add todos or delete them, after refreshing the page they all show up but the last one that i added/deleted. Can i get some help ?

Here is my code and methods where i add/delete them

```
state = {
    todos: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ todos: JSON.parse(ls.get('todos')) })
  }

  addTodo = todo => {
    const newText = todo.text.trim()
    if (newText)
      this.setState({
        todos: [todo, ...this.state.todos]
      })
    ls.set('todos', JSON.stringify(this.state.todos))
  }


  toggleComplete = id => {
    this.setState({
      todos: this.state.todos.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === id)
          return {
            ...todo,
            complete: !todo.complete
          }
        else {
          return todo
        }
      })
    })
  }

  handleDelete = id => {
    this.setState({
      todos: this.state.todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id)
    })
    ls.set('todos', JSON.stringify(this.state.todos))
  }
```

Comment: setState works asynchronous. You can store value you set in variable, and use that variable for setState and ls.set. Also you can rewrite your component to functional with useState and useEffect hooks

Comment: @iofjuupasli `useState` is recommended for primitives values, in this case the best approach should be using `useReducer` in the case you migrate to hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have here is that at the time you are setting the value, state is not yet updated.

`setState` method has a callback that is executed after the work, so you can then be sure that `this.state.todos` was already updated.

```
  addTodo = todo => {
    const newText = todo.text.trim()
    if (newText)
      this.setState({
        todos: [todo, ...this.state.todos]
      }, () => ls.set('todos', JSON.stringify(this.state.todos)))
  }
```

And the same here

```
 handleDelete = id => {
    this.setState({
      todos: this.state.todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id)
    }, () => ls.set('todos', JSON.stringify(this.state.todos)))
  }
```

Comment: you are wellcome ;)